# PHP Curl Post with PayPal's NEW Header Requirement

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I'm using the PHP sample code provided by Paypal for Paypal Payments Pro or Direct Pay. In a recent email from Paypal, they state

> Starting October 7, 2013, we will require all incoming requests to have a “Host” header which complies with HTTP 1.1 Specifications. This header was not required under HTTP 1.0. IPN and PDT scripts using HTTP 1.0 may start failing with “HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request” errors after October 7, 2013, which will result in IPN messages not being validated successfully, or PDT scripts not being able to retrieve transaction information.

They give me the following code to use as the header:

```
$header="POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .="Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .="Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
```

but using CURL, how can I pass all of that?

I know I can set most of that in an array and put it under the CURLOPT_HEADER but what about that FIRST line?

Here's my code. Please help me understand how to correctly add the new header request.

```
$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp_string);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the headers are being stored in a string. To send custom headers with `cURL`, you can uset [`curl_setopt`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) with [`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/curlphp-2003-12/0025.html) as follows:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n",
  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n", 
  "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n",
  "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasnt sure about the POST line since it wasnt a key:pair combination.